# The circle in this code is not displayed correctly on yahoo mail and gmail

Tags: html, css

I am not very good at this, I am a graphic designer but I try to learn the basics of CSS HTML, so I created this circle shape using code that I found here and i am trying to insert it in a newsletter, all looks fine on mobile and certain mailboxes, but on PC yahoo mail and gmail the circle shape is completely wrong!
Can someone help me?

```css
/* Main Container - this controls the size of the circle */

.circle_container {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  /*    border : 2px solid red; */
}


/* Circle Main draws the actual circle */

.circle_main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #197DB5;
  background: #E22227;
  /* can alter thickness and colour of circle on this line */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Circle Text Container - constrains text area to within the circle */

.circle_text_container {
  /* area constraints */
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 70%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* some position nudging to center the text area */
  position: relative;
  left: 15%;
  top: 15%;
  /* preserve 3d prevents blurring sometimes caused by the text centering in the next class */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /*border : 1px solid green;*/
}


/* Circle Text - the appearance of the text within the circle plus vertical centering */

.circle_text {
  /* change font/size/etc here */
  font: 11px "merriweather", Arial, Serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  /* vertical centering technique */
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container">
  <div class="circle_main">
    <div class="circle_text_container">
      <div class="circle_text">80 EUR<br /> PERS
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how is displayed on yahoo and gmail

[image]

This is how is displayed on mobile and roundcube

[image]

Comment: HTML emails are so restricted in most of the email clients. Read about designing email template before doing this. Above code is not suitable for emails. `<table>` with inline styling should be used for HTML emails. 90% of CSS properties are deleted in Gmail emails. So you only have 10% of CSS in Gmail.

Comment: This is what I know already, is there a way to create that shape and display it correcty?

Comment: Start by using your browser dev tools to inspect this element in the yahoo/gmail view, to find out which non-applied property causes this to begin with.

Comment: From what I understand is becasue I used CSS , but I am not sure how to create only in HTML, this is what I need to do... IF I only knew how...